# how to get ul li values in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to get the values of li elements from a ul element, in AangularJS controller and want to store them in an array.

**Html Code**

```
<ul id="list" my-directive>
      <li>A</li>
      <li>B</li>
      <li>C</li>
      <li>D</li>
      <li>E</li>
  </ul>
```

**Controller**

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.newList = [];
  $scope.newList = $('#list li').html();
})
```

What i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you rather render all `li` element using `ng-repeat` only?

```
<ul id="list">
  <li ng-repeat="alphabet in alphabets">A</li>
</ul>
```

**Code**

```
$scope.alphabets = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]
```

---

May be you have some special case where you have rendering data from server side using view engine. Though below is the way to accomplish using directive(still I'd recommend you to use 1st suggested way only)

**Markup**

```
{{myList}}
<ul my-directive="myList">
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>C</li>
  <li>D</li>
  <li>E</li>
</ul>
```

**Directive**

```
.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      var list = scope[attrs.myDirective] = []
      Array.from(element.find('li')).forEach(function(li) {
        list.push(li.innerText)
      });
    }
  }
})
```

[**Demo**](https://plnkr.co/edit/VU2n5Lt99NfwCWHUomnO?p=preview)

Comment: Sir i want to add a templateUrl too, i will use this list array in my template file, if i add templae it donot works

Comment: @TauqeerHassan because inner DOM gets replaced by directive template, I don't understand what you want to achieve, now whatever you're asking is contradicting with your original post..

Comment: No brother i thought i will get a array list and then i will unable to use it in new file but i'm unable to use.

Comment: I edited your code and gave a link of plunker please if you can help me i will be greatful to you

Comment: @TauqeerHassan consider editing your question with update section.. Still I'm unclear with what you need?

Comment: Ok Brother Listen, I have an html file there is a ul list in it where different li elements will be present . i want to make such a directive that if i add directive to a ul list it converts my li elemnts to a <select><option></option>...</select> ldropdown list and use that li values in option element

Comment: @TauqeerHassan so do follow my 1st way, then your can place directive over `ng-repeat` element, and directive will render `select` template in `li`..